Coding for Kleene's closure of any countable alphabet (with textbook reference)
If $S$ is a countable alphabet, I suppose there exists an explicit and effective (i.e. computable) injection from $S^*$ to the set $\mathbb{N}$ of natural numbers. Could you provide a textbook showing this injection? I would also be interested in a textbook which develops computability theory for subsets of $S^*$ using this coding.
